# running into an issue when running query on Impala

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, impala, hue

I've been running into the following issue when running basic queries on Impala (For example: `select * from table limit 100`)  recently. I did some online research but have not found a fix for this. any insights on how I could fix this? I use HUE for querying.

> ExecQueryFInstances rpc query_id=5d4f8d25428xxxx:813cfbd30000xxxx
> failed: Failed to get minimum memory reservation of 8.00 MB on daemon
> ser1830.xxxx.com:22000 for query xxxxxxxxx:813cfbd30xxxxxxxxx
> due to following error: Failed to increase reservation by 8.00 MB
> because it would exceed the applicable reservation limit for the
> "Process" ReservationTracker: reservation_limit=68.49 GB
> reservation=68.49 GB used_reservation=0 child_reservations=68.49 GB
> The top 5 queries that allocated memory under this tracker are:
> Query(5240724f8exxxxxx:ab377425000xxxxxx): Reservation=41.81 GB
> ReservationLimit=64.46 GB OtherMemory=133.44 MB Total=41.94 GB
> Peak=42.62 GB Query(394dcbbaf6bxxxxx2f4760000xxxxxx0):
> Reservation=26.68 GB ReservationLimit=64.46 GB OtherMemory=92.94 KB
> Total=26.68 GB Peak=26.68 GB Query(5d4f8d25428xxxxx:813cfbd30000xxxxx):
> Limit=100.00 GB Reservation=0 ReservationLimit=64.46 GB OtherMemory=0
> Total=0 Peak=0 Memory is likely oversubscribed. Reducing query
> concurrency or configuring admission control may help avoid this
> error.

Comment: So the error is telling you that you don't have enough memory to run all the queries that have been submitted concurrently and it suggests "Reducing query concurrency or configuring admission control may help avoid this error." Have you tried these two possible solutions and did they help?

Comment: This is a common issue with Impala. Either your user doesnt have proper access to run query or use memory. You can connect to hive administrator or you can try connecting through shell.